# Remove default css file

Tags: theming

I need to remove `jquery.ui.theme.css` file, for this in my template.php I implement the below mentioned code:

```
function GNG_css_alter(&$css)
{
unset($css[drupal_get_path('module', 'misc') . '/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css']);
}
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_css_alter().
 */
function seven_css_alter(&$css) {
  // Use Seven's vertical tabs style instead of the default one.
  if (isset($css['misc/vertical-tabs.css'])) {
    unset($css['misc/vertical-tabs.css']['data'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'seven') . '/vertical- tabs.css');
  }
  // Use Seven's jQuery UI theme style instead of the default one.
  if (isset($css['misc/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css'])) {
    unset($css['misc/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css']['data'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'seven') . '/jquery.ui.theme.css');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanku @Adi, I got hint from your answer and solved by using `unset($css['misc/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css']` after `if`statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_library_alter`

```
function garland_library_alter(&$libraries, $module) {
  if ($module == 'system') {
    $js = drupal_get_path('theme', 'garland') . '/ui/ui.garland.css';
    $libraries['ui']['css'][$js] = $libraries['ui']['css']['misc/ui/ui.theme.css'];
    unset($libraries['ui']['css']['misc/ui/ui.theme.css']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have implemented (`drupal_get_path('module', 'misc')`) asks drupal to check for a module which is named misc , which is probably wrong , so when you use drupal_get_path the first parameter is going to be what object are you going to find is it a Module or is a Theme , the next parameter is the machine name of that object . so you cant find a folder which is called misc just by calling this function . this function leads to root of a theme or module.

so the right code is:

```
function GNG_css_alter(&$css)
{
  unset($css[drupal_get_path('THEME or MODULE', 'It's NAME') . '/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css']);
}
```